# Прошу вас, сделайте что-то

Tags: пунктуация

Поймал себя на мысли, что не знаю, чем объяснить запятую в этой фразе. Понятно, что в случае инфинитива запятая не нужна *(прошу вас сделать то-то и то-то),* но у меня 3-е лицо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Поймал себя на мысли, что не знаю, чем объяснить запятую в этой фразе.

Без запятой фраза невозможна по причине нарушения грамматики. "Прошу" - "чего" или "о чем". Сочетание двух личных форм глагола тут совершенно невозможно.

А с запятой "прошу вас" становится вводным. Грамматически (да отчасти и по смыслу) в такой фразе эквивалентно "пожалуйста".

@JimKorbein

> В предложении: «Я прошу сделать что-нибудь» тоже нет запятых.

Абсолютно некорректное заявление. Запятая в подобных примерах не ставится только в случае нерасчленимых выражений. И еще в некоторых отдельно оговариваемых случаях.
Список таких случаев можно  посмотреть здесь.
https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/zapyataya-pered-chem.html

Примеры из Нацкорпуса - все с запятой (за исключением совершенно неавторитетных источников и случаев, подподающих под исключения).

> И я не ***знаю, чем ей помочь***. [Владимир Орлов. Альтист Данилов (1980)]
>
> Мне всегда не хватало дня, сейчас ***я не знаю, чем его заполнить.*** [Ю. М.
> Нагибин. Дневник (1980)]
>
> Стало ли… вот хоть на столько, хоть на крупицу? Луиза смотрела серыми,
> вымершими глазами: ―  ***Я не знаю, чем измерять.*** Нет инструмента… Ольга
> Васильевна еще хотела спросить: «Есть у тебя кто-нибудь?» [Ю. В.
> Трифонов. Другая жизнь (1975)]

И правило, по которому ставится запятая.

> Знак препинания необходимо поставить, ***если союз или местоимение «чем»
> (союзное слово) присоединяет придаточную часть, которая следует за
> главной в сложноподчинённом предложении.***
>
> После дождя грунтовая дорога оказалась более размытой, чем мы
> предполагали.
>
> ***Хозяин хорошо знал, чем удивить своих гостей.***
>
> Среди окружающих он выделялся тем, чем не обладал никто.

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/zapyataya-pered-chem.html

Comment: Спасибо!! Вот я и подумал, что может быть вводным, но, загуглив "прошу вас вводное", ничего не нашёл вразумительного.

Comment: *Вот я и подумал, что может быть вводным* - ой, действительно дискуссионный вопрос. Я стою на той позиции, что список потенциальных вводных слов не исчерпывается приводимыми в учебниках перечнями. Почти любое сочетание, имеющее характер источника информации или чего-то подобного, может стать вводным по воле автора. С другой стороны, противники этого подхода тоже достаточно обоснованно видят в подобных случаях не вводный элемент а бессоюзное сложное. Запятая-то все равно требуется.

Comment: Но мне последнее не очень нравится, поскольку БСП обычно не предполагает явной смысловой подчиненности одной своей части другой. Настолько явной, что первая часть без второй становится бессмысленной.

Comment: «Прошу вас» не имеет никакого отношения к чему-либо отдаленно связанному с вводным словом. Это самые обычные сказуемое и дополнение. Кому вообще может показаться это сочетание вводным сочетанием? Как?

Comment: Я могу пойти и привести 20 примеров из нац.корпуса без запятой.

Answer (score 2):

Предложение выглядит просто, но грамматика у него действительно интересная.

1. **С одной стороны, это БСП** – бессоюзное сложное предложение, состоящее из двух простых. Оба предложения односоставные,  определенно-личные: хотя подлежащего нет, но действующее лицо (я, вы) можно определить по сказуемому.
2. **Отношения между простыми предложениями –** изъяснительные (прошу вас о чем). В БСП в этом случае ставится двоеточие или тире, но допускается и запятая, если нет интонационного предупреждения для более сильных знаков.
3. Казалось бы все ясно, но не совсем. Можно обратить внимание на **свободную позицию предложений** – их можно поменять местами, а это говорит об особенностях грамматики.  Предложение «прошу вас» выглядит  в этом случае как вводное  (тема – **обращение к собеседнику**).

Кстати, **интонация тоже меняется,** так как "сделайте что-нибудь" выделяется голосом как основное сообщение: Прошу вас, сдЕлайте что-то -нибудь.

4. **Почему  оно не приписано к вводным сочетаниям?** Именно потому, что это предложение, а не сочетание. Вводные предложения  могут иметь различный вид, для них главное – это подходящее значение.
   Таким образом, мы имеем образец синтаксической синонимии, когда одну и ту же грамматику можно определить различным способом – БСП или простое предложение, осложненное вводным.

**Примечание.** Такое оформление вводных предложений часто встречается при упрощенной записи дословных высказываний, например:  *Уже поздно, подумал я.*

Comment: Спасибо, Шарон!

Answer (score 1):

В варианте *«Прошу вас, сделайте что-то»* получается сложное предложение, поэтому нужна запятая.

Первая основа: [Я] (подлежащее) прошу (сказуемое).

Вторая основа: [Вы] (подлежащее) сделайте (сказуемое).

---

Вариант *«[Я] прошу вас сделать то-то и то-т»* представляет собой простое предложение, поэтому запятая не нужна.

[Я] (подлежащее) прошу (сказуемое) вас (дополнение) сделать (дополнение).

---

В первом варианте «сделайте» — сказуемое и образует ещё одно простое предложение в составе сложного, а во втором «сделать» — дополнение и является частью простого предложения.

Answer (score -1):

Я не очень понял, в какой фразе вы не знаете чем объяснить запятую, но напишу про всевозможные.

В предложении: «Я не знаю чем объяснить запятую» — вообще нет запятых: после «знаю» запятая не ставится, так как «знаю» и «чем» — это сказуемое и дополнение, а  «чем» и «объяснить» — это дополнение и несогласованное определение.

В предложении: «Я прошу сделать что-нибудь» — также нет запятых: «прошу» и «сделать» — это сказуемое и дополнение-инфинитив. Вот, например, похожее предложение из учебника: «Друзья просили меня сыграть что-нибудь».

Хотя если посмотреть в нац. корпусе, то пунктуация хаотичная (касательно первого предложения) — иногда ставят запятую, иногда нет.
Не знаю чем наполнить ваше существование.  [К. К. Вагинов. Гарпагониада (1934)] (Запятой нету.)
Хотелось бы встретиться с Митькой, но если он уедет на дачу, то совершенно не знаю, чем заниматься, кроме уроков. [Г. С. Эфрон. Дневники. Т. 1. 1940 (1940)] (Запятая стоит.)
Не знаю, чем и как отблагодарить тебя. [С. Т. Григорьев. Александр Суворов (1939)] (Запятая стоит.)
Я не знаю, чем ты еще станешь, Сергей. [В. К. Кетлинская. Мужество (1934-1938)] (Запятая стоит.)
Среди медвежат попадаются, ― не знаю чем это объяснить, ― особи, которые с первого же знакомства с человеком чувствуют к нему особенное расположение. [А. И. Минеев. Пять лет на острове Врангеля (1936)] (Запятая не стоит.)

На первый взгляд, ситуация 70 на 30 в пользу постановки запятой.

На мой взгляд, в такой ситуации не нужно ставить запятую: Мы не ставим запятую в предложениях, как: «Я знаю тебя», «Я знаю много приемов», «Я знаю этот фильм», а местоимение «чем» является таким же дополнением, как соответствующие существительные в этих предложениях.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129002/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett-----).